# Visor CAD para genexus

Tags: .net, genexus

Tengo una aplicación web, done necesitaría poner en un webpanel un visor de archivos CAD, he visto en alguna web, scripts i demas, pero no consigo usarlo correctamente.
Alguien tiene alguna idea de como hacerlo en genexus? con plugin's, Js, etc...

Gracias.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0):

Una opción podría ser en un web panel embeber cualquier sitio que permita visualizar Archivos CAD online, como por ejemplo https://sharecad.org/.

En tu WebPanel, agregas una [embedded page](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?6070,Embedded%20Page%20control)  con el ancho y alto que desees, luego en el evento Start:

```
Event Start
    EmbPage1.Source  = 'https://sharecad.org/'
Endevent
```

Comment: Si, es una opción, pero depender demasiado de una web externa, no me gusta demasiado..